# Django unicode error when removing ImageField from Admin interface

Tags: python, django, unicode, content-management-system

When using the Clear checkbox to remove an uploaded image and clicking Save in the Django Admin interface, I get the following result:

> TypeError at /admin/foo/bar/1/
>
> coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, ImageFieldFile found
>
> Exception Value: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, ImageFieldFile found
>   Exception Location:   /home/ec2-user/ve/Project/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/files/images.py in get_image_dimensions, line 47

I am aware that this is probably to do with the unicode type of the return so have changed from `return image` to `return image.name` in the relevant `ImageField` code but this has not solved the problem. This is the debug log:

```
/home/user/ve/Project/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py
in inner
              return func(*args, **kwargs) ...

/home/user/ve/Project/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py
in change_view
          if form.is_valid(): ...

/home/user/ve/Project/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py
in is_valid
      return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors) ...

/home/user/ve/Project/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py
in _get_errors
          self.full_clean() ...

/home/user/ve/Project/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py
in full_clean
      self._clean_fields() ...

/home/user/ve/Project/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py
in _clean_fields
                  value = field.clean(value, initial) ...

/home/user/Devel/Project/project-cms/project/forms.py in clean
      w, h = get_image_dimensions(image) ...

/home/user/ve/Project/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/files/images.py
in get_image_dimensions
      file = open(file_or_path, 'rb') ...
```

The get_image_dimensions method is imported as such:
from django.core.files.images import get_image_dimensions

This is the body of the clean function:

```
def clean(self, value, initial=None):
    image = super(TheImageField, self).clean(value, initial)
    if image is None: return
    w, h = get_image_dimensions(image)
    if w != TheImageField.required_width or h != TheImageField.required_height:
        error_message = self.error_messages['incorrect_size'] % (w,h,)
        raise util.ValidationError(error_message)
    return image
```

Comment: show us the `get_image_dimensions` function

Answer (score 1):

[The signature for function `get_image_dimensions`](https://github.com/disqus/django/blob/master/django/core/files/images.py) is this one:

```
def get_image_dimensions(file_or_path, close=False)
```

`file_or_path` should be a string to a file in the disk, not an `ImageField`, hence the error.

You can do it like this:

```
def clean(self, value, initial=None):
    image = super(TheImageField, self).clean(value, initial)
    if image is None: return
    # this is where I changed the code to add image.path
    w, h = get_image_dimensions(image.path)
    if w != TheImageField.required_width or h != TheImageField.required_height:
        error_message = self.error_messages['incorrect_size'] % (w,h,)
        raise util.ValidationError(error_message)
    return image
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, changing to `image.path` at that place stopped the crashing but the image does not get removed however. Also, this now makes the uploading of images crash with this log message: `"InMemoryUploadedFile" object has no attribute "path"`

Comment: There seems to be a difference if the clean() is called on upload or delete basically.

Comment: Well, the point of my answer was to point you how `get_image_dimensions` was called incorrectly. You'll have to modify the logic of your `clean` method to get it right.